# How to convert hex to signed long long with python?

Tags: python, signed

I have a hex string `f6befc34e3de2d30`. I want to convert it to signed long long, but

```
x['id'], = struct.unpack('>q', 'f6befc34e3de2d30'.decode('hex'))
```

gives:

```
-0b100101000001000000111100101100011100001000011101001011010000

0b1111011010111110111111000011010011100011110111100010110100110000
```

expected.

Thanks!

Comment: A signed long long can't be larger than 2^63. But your example is, so it's not possible. But you can use unsigned long long: `'>Q'` to get your expected result

Comment: @PaulPanzer Good remark. I have updated my answer with respect to your comment.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, what about treating the first bit as sign?

Comment: Now I understand your problem! The `struct.unpack` does return a negative number, so it does indeed treat the first bit as sign. The `bin`, however, can't do that because as @Anis has explained at some length Python ints are arbitrary size, so in that sense there is no first bit. And `bin` can't know which particulat bit length you have in mind. A work-around is just doing `bin(1<<your_bit_length + your_number)` which will give you the complement representation for the given bit length.

Answer (score 3):

You could do `long('f6befc34e3de2d30', 16)`

```
bin(long('f6befc34e3de2d30', 16))
>>> '0b1111011010111110111111000011010011100011110111100010110100110000'
```

**Edit**: Follow up on @Paul Panzer's comment. That would be true with C type long implementation based on ALU hardware. You could not have signed integer larger that 2^63. However, Python's implementation is different, and relies on array representation of big numbers, and Karatsuba algorithm for arithmetic operations. That is why this method works.

**Edit 2**: Following OPs questions. There is no question of "first bit as sign". In your question you explicitly want to use the long construct of Python, for which the implementation is not the one you expect in the sense that, the representation it uses isn't the same as what you may be familiar with in C. Instead it represents large integers as an array. So if you want to implement some kind of first bit logic, you have to do it yourself. I have no culture or experience in that whatsoever so the following may come completely wrong as someone knowking his stuff, but still let me give you my take on this.

I see two ways of proceeding. In the first one you agree on a convention for the max long you want to work with, and then implement the same kind of logic the ALU does. Let us say for the sake of argument we want to work with sign long in the range `[-2^127, 2^127-1]`. We can do the following

```
MAX_LONG = long('1' + "".join([str(0)]*127), 2)

def parse_nb(s):
    # returns the first bit and the significand in the case of a usual
    # integer representation
    b = bin(long(s, 16))
    if len(b) < 130:  # deal with the case where the leading zeros are absent
        return "0", b[2:]
    else:
        return b[2], b[3:]

def read_long(s):
    # takes an hexadecimal representation of a string, and return
    # the corresponding long with the convention stated above 
    sign, mant = parse_nb(s)
    b = "0b" + mant
    if sign == "0":
        return long(b, 2)
    else:
        return -MAX_LONG + long(b, 2)

read_long('5')
>>> 5L
# fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb is the representation of -5 using the
# usual integer representation, extended to 128 bits integers
read_long("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb")
>>> -5L
```

For the second approach, you don't consider that there a MAX_LONG, but that the first bit is always the sign bit. Then you would have to modify the `parse_nb` method above. I leave that as an exercise :).

Comment: I think in Python 3 it is `bin(int("f6befc34e3de2d30", 16))`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What about treating the first bit as sign?

Comment: How to return signed long long taking the first bit as sign?

Comment: long('f6befc34e3de2d30', 16) is unsigned.

Comment: I've added some suggestions as to how to go about what you seem to be asking